# How to print PDF from IFRAME if src = pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, printing

I have an iframe which needs point directly to a PDF file (not a page with a PDF):

```
<iframe id="ecard-pdf" name="ecard-pdf" style="position: absolute;" src="/profile.pdf">
</iframe>
```

I want to be able to print the PDF in this iFrame

I have found several solutions in other questions that do not fit my needs:

1. Require to have a function in the iframe (
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/473270/1246369 )
2. Suggest focusing the frame and then performing print action on it (
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616706/1246369 )
3. Access contentWindow of the iframe and print it (
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617566/1246369 )
4. Variations of those

However, it seems that FireFox and IE can't do this if the iframe's src points directly to a PDF and not to a page wrapped around the PDF.

**Firefox**:

Instead of printing, it displays this dialog: "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogues" with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons, neither of which prints the PDF.

**IE**:

just ignores my attempts to print using the above methods.

**Question**:

How can I allow users to print the PDF in the iFrame no matter what browser they are using?

Comment: You could fight the browsers, or you could create an HTML wrapper page (e.g. `/printpdf.php?file=/profile.php`) and print that page instead.

Comment: You should check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/812345/792066), seems to get what are you trying working on IE and Firefox.

Comment: you need to specify that the pdf is a file with src="file://..."

Comment: @CS_STEM There's no evidence to suggest this is on the local file system, and even if it were, this question is a year old.

Comment: Just two questions.. do you have a PDF viewer in those browers? is there any probability the specified URL is not the correct one? you may use the absolute route 'http://domain.../document.pdf'

Comment: @QuarK He asked this last year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print a pdf from within an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811272/how-do-i-print-a-pdf-from-within-an-iframe)

Answer (score 6):

I have struggled a bit to find a solution that works for both IE and Chrome. This works for me:

```
$(function() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    var url = '/url/to/file.pdf';
    var pdf ='';
    var style = 'position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;';

    if(msie > 0 || trident > 0 || edge > 0){
        pdf = '<object data="' + url + '" name="print_frame" id="print_frame" style="' + style + '" type="application/pdf">';
    }
    else{
        pdf ='<iframe src="' + url + '" name="print_frame" id="print_frame" style="' + style + '"></iframe>';
    }

    $(document.body).append(pdf);

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.frames["print_frame"].focus();
        window.frames["print_frame"].print();
    },2000);
});
```

...cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested  in this answer for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10654200/2374649), you could do this:

```
window.frames.pdfFrame.print();
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: What about ```embed``` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

I haven't tested this but I found another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096547/2528978

Assuming that you could use the following:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
   body *{display:none}
   iframe{display:block}
</style>
```

So then just the pdf is displayed?

Option 2:

Make a hyperlink to the pdf file that says "Print me"

```
<a href='Path/To/PDF'>Print Me</a>
```

Hope this helps...

-Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
   body *{display:none}
   iframe{display:block}
   </style>
```

So then just the pdf is displayed?

Answer (score -1):

```
const target_iframe = $("#pdfViewerIframe")

target_iframe.attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp], {
                                type: "application/pdf"
                            })))

target_iframe[0].contentWindow.print()
```

NOTE: `resp` is pdf you get from server

Answer (score -2):

You can use directly window print option.
use onclick option

onclick="javascript:window.print();"

Comment: Will not print the pdf content inside iframe