# Object doesn't support property 'print' IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, printing

Currently i have an iframe with a pdf file embed and i wanted to print this pdf, but when i tried to print it it shows me the next message: `Object doesn't support property 'print'`.

This is my current iframe code:

```
<iframe height="329" id="pdf1" src="file.pdf" style="width: 100%;" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("pdf1").focus();
document.getElementById("pdf1").print();
```

This is the way some sites recomended but still have no success. My current PDF reader is Acrobat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888131/print-pdf-file-in-iframe-using-javascript-getting-one-page-only) - has tips on how to invoke print, assumes you can use `<object>` instead of `<iframe>`

Comment: The problem with the object is that makes a double head request and that's why i'm using the <iframe> element.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656271/how-to-print-pdf-from-iframe-if-src-pdf)

Comment: I don't meant to print directly, i want to show the preview print dialog