# Printing from iframe works everywhere except IE11

Tags: javascript

I've written code that displays a pdf blob onto the screen of an iframe, but I also want it to print.  I have this working in all browsers execept for IE11.  Anyone know the solution there?  I read some where about execCommand, but that didn't seem to work either.

```
const printElem = (invoice) => {
  const origiframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  if (origiframe) {
    origiframe.remove();
  }
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = invoice;
  iframe.name = 'pdf-frame';
  iframe.id = 'pdf-frame';
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  window.frames['pdf-frame'].print();
}
```

**UPDATE**: I should be able to use something like the following to get the print to work across all browsers, but unclear on the syntax:

```
window.frames['pdf-frame'].document.execCommand('print',false,null);
```

**UPDATE2**: I'm trying to use the following as well, but still no dice.  Anyone have any thoughts on why the catch portion won't work in IE11?

```
try {
  window.frames['pdf-frame'].print();
} catch(e) {
  window.frames['pdf-frame'].document.execCommand('print',false,null);
}
```

Comment: What is the error in IE11?

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'print'

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774184/object-doesnt-support-property-print-ie-11. That question has a comment with a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888131/print-pdf-file-in-iframe-using-javascript-getting-one-page-only which may solve your question.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst that does not help solve my issue.  I'm using an iframe and everything works just fine in all browsers except for IE11.  I would like to keep my setup, but append to it for IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this this?

```
var target= document.getElementById("myFrame");
try {
    target.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
} catch(e) {
    target.contentWindow.print();
}
```

Comment: This brings in an error of 'Unable to get property 'print' of undefined or null reference', yet the iframe is on the screen with the correct id.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I use your code to target the iframe for print, it no longer outputs the data.  Only my code prints out the data.

Comment: if you test this on your browser ie 11 it doesnt work? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYOvJG im not in front of computer atm

Comment: Unfortunately, CodePen doesn't work in IE11.  I tried firing up your pen, but CodePen said it would only work in a different mode, which I would have to pay for.

Comment: So, based on what I saw on another post, it looks like I should be able to use window.frames['pdf-frame'] to grab the contentWindow, but now I'm unsure how to make this statement work:
window.frames['pdf-frame'].document.execCommand('print',false,null);

Comment: I went ahead and approved your answer as it is the best answer possible for most browsers, but I actually wound up using a library called printJS that works quite well for the browsers that actually allow printing from an iframe.  The other browsers I'm just opening the pdf in another tab as a default.